# How do you subscribe to changes to ObservableObject from within NSViewControllerRepresentable?

Tags: swiftui, nsviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have a NSCollectionView I am trying to use with a SwiftUI application but need to access an ObservableObject (singleton) - I can access the singleton but can't seem to use Swift .observe nor can I find any reference to using ObservableObject from with the view controller.

Comment: Would you show your code of where is dependency between ObservableObject and your  UIKit component (controller?) and what you want to observe?

Comment: I have a NSViewControllerRepresentable embedded in a SwiftUI view with the main model object a singleton ObservableObject.  Usually I would just use bindings or KVO but I just wonder whether it is possible to use the ObservedObject within the NSViewController - I can't find any specific mention that Combine will only work with SwiftUI.

Comment: For now I just turned the model object into a NSObject subclass and use KVO to observe properties.